# How can i get information from a map (type)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

You have for example this interface that hold a map with number, viewmodel.

```
     interface KlagenemnderPageProps {
            besvarelsePlagiatstatus: Map<number, BesvarelsePameldingViewModel>;
        }

render (){

console.log(
            "Object",
            this.props.besvarelsePlagiatstatus.get(70272)
        );

}
```

This returns a object and i'd like to access these values.
[image]

Comment: this is the info from the console.log, i'd like to get the "erTodeltEksamen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.props.besvarelsePlagiatstatus.get(70272)` returns an object than you can access `erTodeltEksamen` with `this.props.besvarelsePlagiatstatus.get(70272).erTodeltEksamen`...